# Qual è il significato di "schiarirsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Mi sentivo contenta anch'io e mi pareva di vedere la piazza grande, lucida dell'ultima pioggia caduta, con tutte quelle persone che parlavano e **si schiarivano**. Ma noi donne non possiamo uscire tranne quando è la festa e tutto il paese è fuori a vedere i santi per le strade e i palloni di cartavelina che si colorano e si perdono, come macchie rosse, fra le nuvole.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "schiarirsi" in questo brano? Ho cercato il verbo "schiarire" in parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso che l'accezione di [schiarirsi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schiarire/) adatta al contesto da te citato sia quella figurata che significa rasserenarsi:

> In usi fig.: *a quella notizia, vidi la sua fronte,* o *il suo sguardo*,
>   *schiarirsi*, rasserenarsi;

Dal dizionario dei sinonimi e contrari Treccani per [schiarirsi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schiarire_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> b. (fig.) [di volto e sim., ritornare sereno: *a quella notizia, vidi
>   il suo sguardo s.*] ≈ rallegrarsi, rasserenarsi, rischiararsi.

Comment: Mi sembra di capire dal dizionario, che questo verbo con questo significato si usi per il volto, lo sguardo, ecc. Si può anche usare per una persona?

Comment: Direi di sì, può anche riguardare lo stato d'animo di una persona

Comment: Il volto è di frequente, nel linguaggio letterario italiano, sinonimo (in un certo senso) dello stato d'animo. Si vede fuori qualcosa che accade dentro.